# SSRS String -vs- Data Integer

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am working on a SSRS report and using a parameter that allows you to choose multiple options.  However, when I do this I get an error that states:

Error Converting Data Type nVarChar to Int.

The data in the database is an Integer.  The parameter is set up as an Integer and it works great when only choosing one option.  The issue comes when I choose multiple options.

My co-worker came up with one work-around but I would like something a little more elegant and easier to plug in if possible.

Here is his work-around:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DtaPrep_MktgClients]
                     @BegDate   date = NULL
                   , @EndDate date = NULL 
                   , @Species varchar(50) = 'canine,feline,K9,' 
                 , @HospList varchar(500) = NULL 


This is where the hospmastid string gets converted into a temp table
/*
                   --===================================--
                                                          HOSPITALS SETUP
                   --===================================--
*/
          If @HospList IS NOT NULL
                   BEGIN

                             DECLARE @WorkHospList varchar(500) 
                             SET @WorkHospList = @HospList 
                             ; 
                             CREATE TABLE #HospList
( HospID        smallint  NULL ) 


                             SET @CommaLoc =    charindex(',', @WorkHospList)  
                             WHILE @CommaLoc  > 1 
                                      BEGIN
                                                SET @curVal = LEFT(@WorkHospList, @commaloc-1 ) 

                                                INSERT INTO
                                                          #HospList( HospID ) 
                                                SELECT @curVal 

                                                SET @WorkHospList = substring( @WorkHospList, @commaloc+1, len(@WorkHospList) ) 
                                                SET @CommaLoc =    charindex(',', @WorkHospList)  

                                       END    
                   END


This is using the temp table to accomplish the same thing as a “WHERE Hospmastid IN (101,102,103)…” 

Method 1
SELECT
HospitalMasterID
          , ClientID
          , FirstName
          , LastName 
FROM 
          Client 
WHERE
          HospitalMasterID IN (Select HospID From #HospList )
```

Needless to say, I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this.  If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Here is the full Query I am now using.  But it is not selecting anything so there is an issue with the Created Table.

```
USE [xxxxx]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PriceErosion]    Script Date: 11/26/2013 8:26:33 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 11/25/2013
-- Description: Determines the products in which the price was lowered and revenue lost during a set time period.
-- =============================================
*/



    --@StartDate as Date = Null
    --,@EndDate as Date = Null
    --,@CurDate as Date = Null
    --,@Hospital as VarChar = Null
    --,@Division as Int = Null



Declare @StartDate as Date = Null
Declare @EndDate as Date = Null
Declare @Hospital as Int = Null
Declare @Division as Int = Null
DECLARE @curDate Date   = Null

SET @curDate = GETDATE() 
Set @StartDate = CASE WHEN @StartDate IS NULL THEN DATEADD(dd, -31, Dateadd(dd, -1, @curdate) ) ELSE @StartDate END
Set @EndDate = CASE WHEN @EndDate IS NULL THEN Dateadd(dd, -1, @curdate) ELSE @EndDate END 
Set @Hospital = Case When @Hospital IS Null Then '3' Else @Hospital End;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#HospList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #HospList ; 

If @Hospital IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @WorkHospList varchar(500) 
        Declare @CommaLoc as Int
        Declare @curVal as int
        SET @WorkHospList = @Hospital 
        ; 
        CREATE TABLE #HospList
        ( HospID        smallint  NULL ) 

        SET @CommaLoc =    charindex(',', @WorkHospList)  
        WHILE @CommaLoc  > 1 
            BEGIN
                SET @curVal = LEFT(@WorkHospList, @commaloc-1 ) 
                INSERT INTO
                #HospList( HospID ) 
                SELECT @curVal 
                SET @WorkHospList = substring( @WorkHospList, @commaloc+1, len(@WorkHospList) ) 
                SET @CommaLoc =    charindex(',', @WorkHospList)  
                END    
            END

Begin

    --  Sets the Baseline Price Date in the PriceChangeHistory Table.
    With PC1
    as
        (Select
            HospitalMasterID
            ,TxnCode
            ,UserInfoMasterID
            ,Active
            ,min(TxnDateTime) as StartingDate
        From
        PriceChangeHistory
        Where
        TxnDateTime Between @StartDate and @EndDate
        Group By
            HospitalMasterID, TxnCode, UserInfoMasterID, Active)

    -- Gets the Baseline Price for the period from the PriceChangeHistory Table
    ,PC
    as
        (Select
            PC1.HospitalMasterID
            ,PC1.TxnCode
            ,PC1.UserInfoMasterID
            ,PC1.Active
            ,Cast (PC1.StartingDate as Date) as StartingDate
            ,PC2.OldPrice as StartingPrice
            ,PC2.NewPrice
            ,PC2.TxnSubType
        From
        PC1
        Inner Join
        PriceChangeHistory as PC2
        On
        PC1.HospitalMasterID = PC2.HospitalMasterID
        and
        PC1.TxnCode = PC2.TxnCode
        and
        PC1.StartingDate = PC2.TxnDateTime
        Where
        PC2.OldPrice > PC2.NewPrice)

    --MedicalHistory Information
    ,MH
    as
        (Select
            HospitalMasterID
            ,PatientID
            ,TxnDate
            ,TxnCode
            ,Description
            ,ListAmount
            ,ExtendedAmount
            ,TxnType
            ,Quantity
            ,(Case
                When Quantity <> '1' Then (ListAmount/Quantity)
                Else ListAmount
                End) as UnitPrice
        From
            MedicalHistory
        Where
            TxnDate Between @StartDate and @EndDate
            and
            _IsServOrITem = 1)

    -- Determines the Revenue lost per each sale, also reduces the results to only those items where the Price was lowered not raised.
    ,RL
    as
        (Select
            PC.HospitalMasterID
            ,MH.PatientID
            ,PC.TxnCode
            ,PC.TxnSubType
            ,MH.Description
            ,PC.UserInfoMasterID as ChangedByUserID
            ,MH.TxnDate
            ,PC.StartingPrice
            ,Cast (MH.UnitPrice as Money) as UnitPrice
            ,Cast ((StartingPrice - UnitPrice) as Money) as RevenueLost
        From 
        PC
        Left OUter Join
        MH
        on
        PC.HospitalMasterID = MH.HospitalMasterID
        and
        PC.TxnCode = MH.TxnCode
        Where
        PC.StartingPrice > MH.UnitPrice)

    --- Determine the name of the tech changing the prices.
    ,UI
    as
        (Select
            HospitalMasterID
            ,UserInfoMasterID
            ,Name
        From
            UserInfo)

    --- Get the Division and Hospital Name for each Hospital.

    ,HODI
    as
        (Select
            DI.DivisionID
            ,DI.DivisionName
            ,HO.HospMastID
            ,HO.HospCode
            ,HO.HospName
        From
            ref_Hospital as HO
            inner Join
            ref_Division as DI
            on
            HO.DivisionID = DI.DivisionID)

    ,HI
    as
        (Select
            HODI.DivisionID
            ,HODI.DivisionName
            ,RL.HospitalMasterID
            ,HODI.HospCode
            ,HODI.HospName
            ,RL.PatientID
            ,RL.TxnCode
            ,RL.TxnSubType
            ,RL.Description
            ,RL.ChangedByUserID
            ,RL.TxnDate
            ,RL.StartingPrice
            ,RL.UnitPrice
            ,RL.RevenueLost
        From
            RL
            Left Outer Join
            HODI
            ON
            RL.HospitalMasterID = HODI.HospMastID
            Where
            TXNDate Between @StartDate and @EndDate)

Select
*
From
HI
Where
HospitalMasterID in (Select HospID from #Hosplist)
Order By
HOspitalMasterID
end
```

Comment: post your original query

Comment: I edited the above post with the full Query.

Comment: Can you explain which of the stored procedure parameters is associated with the multi-value parameter in your report? Please give all the details e.g. the settings on the report parameter and exactly which part of your SQL query this relates to.

Comment: Sam, yes it is set to Integer however- I found this is a common problem with SSRS.

Comment: Nathan,  the @Hospital parameter.  What is really bugging me on this is that it runs perfectly fine in SSMS as a straight query with results, it is only in SSRS that I have an issue.  I have tested it in SSMS by using both a Execute Command as well as Using Test variables.  It also relates directly to the HI Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to SQL Server 2008, the standard way to filter by one or more values was to pass an XML document to the Stored Procedure and join on it. In this case, you could pass the data as a string with the integers separated by commas, then convert that into an XML document, then join on the XML. So you should change the multiselect in SSRS to a text datatype. Here's a post that shows you how to open an XML document: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/

SQL Server 2008 lets you use table-valued parameters, but again, it might be best to pass the data as a string of comma separated integers and then let the stored procedure put the data into a table-valued parameter, and then join on that. Here's a post that describes how to use table valued parameters: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Thanks, will try that if need be.  Right now got beyond it by limiting the search to one Division as opposed to Hospital